# Define a color of the pressed button of a SetterBar

Tags: formatting

It is easy to define a background color for the SetterBar buttons, so that all the buttons that are not pressed have the specified color, while the pressed one is gray.
Here is the example:

```
SetterBar[2, Range[5], Background -> LightBlue]
```

in which the buttons that are not pressed are LightBlue.

How to make another way around? That is, how to make all buttons gray except the pressed one, which should take a specified color?

Comment: On my system, V9.0.1 on OS X, setting the background color of a setter bar has _no_ effect on the color of the buttons in bar, pressed or unpressed. What is your setup?

Comment: @m_goldberg He's probably working on Windows. It is working here.

Comment: @m_goldberg PC, Win7, Mma 9.01

Answer (score 4):

There were always problems with getting `SetterBar` the proper look.

I think the fastest, but not the cleanest, way is to make it with `Panel`/`Pane`/`Framed`:

```
pan[i_] := Panel[Style[i, Bold, Black, 12], FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {20, 20}, 
                 Alignment -> Center, Background -> If[x == i, Red, Blue]];

SetterBar[Dynamic@x, Thread[Range[5] -> Table[With[{i = i}, Dynamic@pan[i]], {i, 5}]], 
          Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]

Watch out on `x`. Probably you may want to put it into `DynamicModule` for proper scope.

Comment: As for the global `x`, would it not be enough to add a second argument to `pan`, like so: `pan[i_, k_] := Panel[Style[i, Bold, White, 12], FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {20, 20}, Alignment -> Center, Background -> If[k == i, Red, Blue]]`? Also, note that `Black` is replaces with `White`; numbers on the button look much better in white when displayed on red and blue backgrounds.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for the suggestion. This is a possibility, of course, and I have it in mind. My question concerned more the built-in Mma options. I just had an impression that I missed something elementary in the documentation, since for me the desire to highlight the pressed button looks more natural than the one of highlighting all except the pressed one. Thank you once more, but let us wait a bit in case something else pops up.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch yes ofcourse :) I'm afraid `SetterBar` is tough to customize. There were similar questions about button size for it and the solutions were similar. So I think there isn't any built-in functionality. But I would like to see it too, not need to hurry :)

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for remarks. :) I agree but I will leave it as it is, I think it will not affect the message which is how to make `SetterBar` which behaves like OP wants.